# OSX/Cocoa Problems creating Status Bar Item (Apple guide not working for me)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I believe I'm following the example correctly. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/Tasks/creatingitems.html)

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSStatusItem *testItem;
NSMenu *testMenu;
}
```

...

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    testMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    [testMenu addItemWithTitle:@"An Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:nil];
    [testMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Another Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:nil];

    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];

    testItem = [[NSStatusItem alloc] init];
    testItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [testItem setTitle: @"X"];
    [testItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [testItem setMenu:testMenu];
    [testItem setEnabled:YES];
}
```

I build and run. No new status bar item to be seen. Why not? Forgive me if I'm being an ignorant newbie. I assume I'm overlooking something fundamental.

Comment: Perhaps your status bar is full and NSStatusBar is unable to find space for your menu item.  Check if it's nil, as that's usually what it does if it can't find space for it.

Answer (score 5):

`keyEquivalent` for `addItemWithTitle` cannot be nil. When you do, an exception occurs so it never makes it past those lines. Change those two lines with something like this:

```
[testMenu addItemWithTitle:@"An Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@"a"];
[testMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Another Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@"i"];
```

And everything works fine now. You can troubleshoot these kind of issues by looking at the debugger's output. In this case, the output that gave the right clues was "Invalid parameter not satisfying: charCode != nil".

You can get more from [`NSMenu's` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsmenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenu/addItemWithTitle:action:keyEquivalent:):

> A string identifying the key to use as a key equivalent for the menu item. If you do not want the menu item to have a key equivalent, keyEquiv should be an empty string (@"") and not nil.

Comment: True that! Also, if you don't wanna have a keyEquivalent just supply an empty string @"" and if you want Command-A use @"a" (not @"A").

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something fundamental. Should have been the first thing I'd checked. `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` was not being called. Fixed now.